# Why is my cardview getting clipped

Tags: android, android-xml, android-cardview

I am using CardView as the parent in my list row layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_img"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="82dp"
                    android:layout_height="82dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/universal_button_blue_background"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
            </RelativeLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

On the XML preview all is fine, I get the elevation and corners: 
[image]

However on the device, my view is clipped it seems:

[image]

Here is my ListView definition:

```
<ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting this attribute to your cardview tag    card_view:borderWidth="0dp"

Comment: Here is the proper one `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`

Comment: Also Instead of using padding in your LinearLayout(row layout) define android:margin="15 dp" in your CardView tag

Answer (score 2):

In your *LinearLayout* use `android:clipToPadding="false"` to prevent clipping the children because of a padding.

In this screenshot you see two Card Views in a *LinearLayout* not clipped
[image: Two card views not clipped by padding]

For more visit [the Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#attr_android:clipToPadding)

Comment: Adding up to @iboalali 's answer, adding `android:paddingBottom="5dp"` to the immediate parent of the cardview can help.